# How do I call a file imported through tkinter filedialog?

Tags: python, dataframe, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a very simple GUI that will import a file, run it through some data formatting code, and export it as an .xlsx file

The file would be an excel file. An example would be:

```
col1 
a        
b
c
```

and my current python script does this:

```
df = read_excel('file.xlsx')
mapping = {'a':'apple','b':'banana','c':'carrot'}
df = df.replace({"col1":mapping}, regex=True)
```

and it returns:

```
col1
apple
banana
carrot
```

but now I am trying to create a GUI that will run it instead (:

This is the code I have so far (I get the error ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime, date

def UploadAction(event=None):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    print('Selected:', filename)

    df = pd.DataFrame(eval(data=filename))

    mmapping = {'a':'apple','b':'banana','c':'carrot'}

    df = df.replace({"col1":mapping}, regex=True)

    print(df['col1'])

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Open', command=UploadAction)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

For the excel export, I know the code should be:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("newfile.xlsx",
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        datetime_format='yyyymmdd',
                        date_format='yyyymmdd')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = ('Sheet1'))

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.set_column('B:C', 20)
writer.save()
```

but I am not sure of how to include it in the GUI program.

So what would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

=^..^=

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


def open_file():
    # open file
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    # load data into data frame
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=" ", header=None)

    return data


root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Open', command=open_file)
button.pack()

# do something with data
df_data = open_file()
df = df_data.drop(0, axis=1)

# save data to excel
df.to_excel("output.xlsx")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: hey, thank you so much! your code makes sense but I'm still getting an error (utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa2 in position 0: invalid start byte). do you know why?

Comment: @Brunna T. probably pandas have problems to read you file. Try use decode options.